# deleted bookmark folders in Chrome, Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I just had my computer repaired and when I got it back, with Windows 8, my folders in Bookmarks were gone. Is there any way they can be retrieved? They are very important.

Comment: you should use the Chrome feature that syncs your data with your Google account in the future. that way, if your computer burst into flames, you still have your bookmarks

Answer (score 0):

*Unfortunately we have no idea what happened to your files, so it is impossible to know for sure.*

Chrome can import bookmarks from itself or from other browsers though, so you need to find a file somewhere first. Search you entire disk for files called bookmark.html or restore it from a backup, then CTRL-SHIFT-O opens the bookmark manager and from there you can import bookmarks in a number of ways, including from other browsers.